# Getting a cryptic error on my simple Java program, comparing char[i] to a string

Tags: java, char

```
public static void ejemplosString(String palabra){
        char[] letras = palabra.toCharArray();
        int contadorVocales = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {            
            if (char[i] == 'a') {
                contadorVocales++;                
            }

            if (char[i] == "e") {
                contadorVocales++;                
            }

            if (char[i] == "i") {
                contadorVocales++;                
            }

            if (char[i] == "o") {
                contadorVocales++;                
            }

            if (char[i] == "u") {
                contadorVocales++;                
            }
        }
    }
```

Getting the error on every If statement. Any guidance?

Even when changing the vowels to single quotes, I still get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unexpected type
  required: value
  found:    class
        at practico1.Main.ejemplosString(Main.java:64)
        at practico1.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable name is `letras` not `char`

Comment: What a glaring mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the double-quotes around your letters to single quotes.  It looks like the 'a' is correct (it's a character literal), but the other letters ("e", "i", etc.) are all string literals.

Answer (score 3):

**Strings** use a double quote `"`, but **Characters** use a single quote `'`. Since you are comparing characters, you need to switch to single quotes.

Also, `char[i]` is not valid java. I think you meant `letras[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using a `.equals()` method to compare strings?

Answer (score 0):

Naveen already gave the right answer

I wanted to add that you could also use the

[Java Switch Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

to implement this Function